# Show command prompt on reboot

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface

In one of my linux machines, when i give `reboot` command at the shell command prompt then press enter, i get another command prompt and then the system reboots.

```
$reboot
$
```

But in one of my office Linux machines, when i give the reboot command, it suddenly reboots without showing another shell command prompt

What could be the reason for this? I need the first behavior to be present in my office machine also. Kindly tell me where i should tweak my office machine.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, why do you need this behavior?  Also, are the linux distributions different or are they all the same?  What flavor of linux are you running?

Comment: I am also curious why such behavior occurs. I thought if there is some reason, i should find it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your first describes linux box has a timeperiod set to wait before doing the actual reboot. To get to now more about the shutdown/reboot process in your linux distro, take a look at `man shutdown`. It will explain, where the configuration is placed.

In my distribution, SUSE, these are some files which are part of the shutdown process:

- `/etc/inittab`
- `/etc/init.d/halt`
- `/etc/init.d/reboot`

Comment: +1 Correct and consider that the **reboot** command will normally call a **shutdown -r**, that will send a SIGTERM to all the processes. This will give a bit of time to exit cleanly (and here the behavior you experience at home).